# Enable In App purchase is not shown

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i am following the below link...

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-in-app-purchases/

In that link they have given like below

> "After logging into the Provisioning
>   Portal, select the “App IDs” tab.
>   Click “New App ID.” You will need to
>   enter a common name and a unique
>   bundle identifier. The common name
>   will be used to identify this App ID
>   within the Provisioning Portal and the
>   Bundle Identifier is a unique
>   identifier for your actual application
>   binary. When developing an application
>   that will use in-app purchases, you
>   must use a full Bundle Identifier. No
>   “wild card” IDs are allowed. Click
>   submit. You will be taken back to the
>   main App IDs page. Find your newly
>   created App ID in the list, and then
>   click the “Configure” link to the
>   right of it.On the “Configure App ID”
>   screen, select the check box next to
>   “Enable In App Purchase” and click the
>   “Done” button:"

But for me...

In the Provisioning portal, "Enable In App Purchase " check box is not shown

But enable for Apple Push notification service is shown..

why the "Enable In App Purchase" is not shown…

Comment: Have you signed and had approved the paid iOS applications contract?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like Apple's policy changed, according to the [How To](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles/howto.action), in the section "Registering an App ID for In App Purchases and Game Center":

> All explicit App IDs are automatically
>   enabled for In App Purchase and Game
>   Center. Wildcard App IDs and
>   duplicates of existing explicit App
>   IDs are ineligible for In App Purchase
>   and Game Center.